# replacing stdout and stdin with a file pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, posix

I have a sandbox code written in c.It has the following line in it:
`msb.sbox.task.ofd = STDOUT_FILENO;`. That is output for the executable is written to
standard output.I want to change this so the output is written to a file instead.I tried doing
this

```
  FILE * fp;
  fp=fopen("myf","w");
  msb.sbox.task.ofd=fp;
```

But this gives the warning `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`.How do i go about it ??

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is Posix, not C++.

Comment: sorry for that I did not know

Comment: @sashasami shouldn't you open the file for writing, no reading?

Comment: @Adam yeah!! sorry corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
  FILE * fp;
  fp=fopen("myf","r");
  msb.sbox.task.ofd=fileno(fp);
```

`STDOUT_FILENO` is an `int`, and `fp` is a pointer to a `FILE` struct, so your assignment isn't correct.
`fileno` will return the file descriptor (the `int` value) from a pointer to a `FILE` struct, that what is `fp`.

Answer (score 4):

If looks like the structure member is expecting a file id number rather than a pointer to a streamed file buffer. Use `fileno` to acquire the id from `FILE*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * fp;
fp=fopen("myf","r");
msb.sbox.task.ofd=fileno(fp);
```